# Hide weight and dimensions fields from product variations settings in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a website that does not need the shipping weight and dimensions in WooCommerce. On the admin area - when adding a new product, there is the shipping tab which has this option. Is there a way to hide it? I tried using the following CSS but it did not work. I have been looking for a way to use my functions.php file to remove it but cannot figure out how. Here is what I tried:

```
p.form-field._weight_field {display:none;}

p.form-field .dimensions_field {display:none;}

.woocommerce_options_panel .options_group:first-child{display:none 
!important;}
```

I tried that in multiple variations with no luck. Does anyone know of a way to use the functions.php file and hide just the weight and dimensions input area?

Comment: Can you please share more details, like the html for the section in question? If your css isn't working, it's possible something else is overriding it.

Comment: This is within Wordpress using WooCommerce. It is in PHP. Those were just the CSS selectors I found using the inspect function on the browser.

Comment: The php outputs html. Using the inspect function on the browser can also show you the html that the css is being applied to. If you do a search for "how to inspect tool html" you should find some helpful links demonstrating how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding product weight and dimensions fields in Admin product pages settings.

**1) For product post type** you will use:

```
// Products
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'hide_product_weight_and_dimentions' );
function hide_product_weight_and_dimentions(){
    ?><style>
        div#shipping_product_data ._weight_field, div#shipping_product_data .dimensions_field { display:none !important;}
    </style><?php
}
```

**2) For Product variations** you will use:

```
// Variations
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'hide_variation_weight_and_dimentions', 10, 3 );
function hide_variation_weight_and_dimentions( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){
    ?><style>
        .variable_weight<?php echo $loop ?>_field, .dimensions_field { display:none !important;}
    </style><?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**On a simple product:**

[image]

**On a product variation from a variable product:**

[image]

Comment: That worked. That was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the tab on the left (and therefore keep anyone from getting to the weight, dimensions or shipping class fields):

```
#woocommerce-product-data ul.wc-tabs li.shipping_options.shipping_tab {
    display: none;
}
```

If you just want to hide weight and dimension fields:

```
#shipping_product_data .form-field._weight_field, 
#shipping_product_data .form-field.dimensions_field {
    display: none;
}
```