# Hide/unset product variation option fields woocomerce settings

Tags: woocommerce, field, settings

i use this code snippet to hide some specific option fields in admin product settings:

```
add_filter( 'product_type_options', function( $options ) {

    // remove "Virtual" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'virtual' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'virtual' ] );
    }
    // remove "Downloadable" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'downloadable' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'downloadable' ] );
    }
        // remove "Downloadable" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'service' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'service' ] );
    }
            // remove "Downloadable" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'used_good' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'used_good' ] );
    }  
            // remove "Downloadable" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'defective_copy' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'defective_copy' ] );
    }
                // remove "Downloadable" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'differential_taxation' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'differential_taxation' ] );
    }
                // remove "Food" checkbox
    if( isset( $options[ 'is_food' ] ) ) {
        unset( $options[ 'is_food' ] );
    }

    return $options;

} );
```

However this snippet only affects single product, i also want to unset those fields for variation options fields.

[Variation fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsdEI.png)

I want to unset these fields.

[Dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY2qY.png)

And all the lines from the dropdown menu except the top 3 lines.

How can i achiev that? Any help would greatly appreciated.

---

I tried this snippet from here:
[Hide weight and dimensions fields from product variations settings in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732422/hide-weight-and-dimensions-fields-from-product-variations-settings-in-woocommerc)

```
// Variations
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'hide_variation_weight_and_dimentions', 10, 3 );
function hide_variation_weight_and_dimentions( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){
    ?><style>
        .variable_weight<?php echo $loop ?>_field, .dimensions_field { display:none !important;}
    </style><?php
}
```

But it works only partial, i can not target the lines in dropdown menu and shipping class